# Xamarin: GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations missing in iOS 8?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

```
    public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations ()
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All;
    }
```

When I try to compile this (working code in iOS 7) in Xamarin for iOS 8 it errors out saying **GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations**() is not a method

Comment: It's still there in `UIViewController`. What's the type (and it's base classes) that you're trying to override ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a breaking change in the 8.0 beta release (and we're looking into fixing it) that affects `UISplitViewController`.

A workaround is to use the newer, `*Delegate`-based property, that was introduced (and broke the `override`) like this:

```
using (UISplitViewController svc = new UISplitViewController ()) {
    svc.GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations = (UISplitViewController) => UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All;
}
```

**note: the next beta (and final) version of XI 8.0 have the fix and the override will work normally.**